# How to get a list of articles selected by tags whithin a menu or submenu

Tags: list, menu, tags, article, joomla3.3

Is there any possibility to get a list of Joomla 3 articles selected by a specific tag whithin a menu/submenu ?

eg:

- Menu Point 1

  - Sub Menu Point 1

    - Article 1 (with tag 1)
    - Article 2 (with tag 1)
    - ...
  - Sub Menu Point 2

    - Article 1 (with tag 2)
    - Article 2 (with tag 2)
    - ...

Thanks a lot for your help!
Regards!